# How to count the number of zeros in a decimal?

Tags: python

What is the most efficient way to calculate the number of 0s in a decimal before the first non 0 number?

Desired outcome:

```
0.0000456 ---> 4
0.00406 ---> 2
0.000456 ---> 3
```

So far I have tried mathematically this (which is slow):

```
from math import floor, log

def num_zeros(decimal):
    return 10 - floor(log(decimal *10e10,10))
```

and this (which is not right as 0 after a first number will be counted):

```
def count_0(number):
    n = format(number, 'f').count('0')
    return n - 1
```

Comment: Could you outline what your have considered trying?

Comment: Do you have source code for what you've already tried?

Comment: What you're asking for is, essentially, the negation of the base-10 logarithm of the number, rounded towards zero (or equivalently, truncated). Note, however, that as Mark says, your number may actually be unrepresentable in floating point, and the result might be off by one if the representation is smaller than your desired number.

Comment: While your solution with `log` has some issues, I can't believe it's slower than converting the number to a string.

Comment: The decimal (string) representation of a `float` value is often not its true value (because that cannot be represented in base 10). From the code in your question, it looks like you're OK with that—correct?

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply:

```py
from math import floor, log10, inf

def num_zeros(decimal):
    return inf if decimal == 0 else -floor(log10(abs(decimal))) - 1
```

This handles 0.001 correctly (2 zeros), whereas some answers would print 3. It also now works for negative numbers and zero.

I'd be *shocked* if string methods were faster.

---

To handle **non-finite** numbers correctly as well, simply swap out the definition of `floor` as follows:

```py
def floor(decimal):
    return math.floor(decimal) if math.isfinite(decimal) else decimal
```

Or equivalently:

```py
from math import floor, log10, inf, isinf, nan, isnan

def num_zeros(decimal):
    if isnan(decimal):
        return nan
    if isinf(decimal):
        return -inf
    return inf if decimal == 0 else -floor(log10(abs(decimal))) - 1
```

Comment: Nice answer, however, it does not work for negative numbers

Comment: @user88484 nice catch. I've updated my answer to work with negative numbers and zero as well!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to approach this using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
# Update, simplified sol thanks to @Aran-Fey's comments
import re
s = '0.0000456'
len(re.search('\d+\.(0*)', s).group(1))
#4
```

Comment: But we do not know whether this is <str> or <float> ;-). Of course, the way would first be to transfer `<float>` to `<str>` type and then simply count all zeros, because there are many functions in Python to work with the string.

Comment: Is regex really required here? I feel like it's just adding overhead to what would have been a simple string parse.

Comment: perhaps you're right @JordanSinger... just thought I'd add a regex solution in case it may be of help for OP

Comment: Let me check @Aran-Fey

Comment: It will not work with numbers without decimal point. you could look ahead rather than making deicmal point stringent. Not sure how OP expects

Comment: This fails when the number of 0s is greater than 3 I am not sure why.

Comment: @PacoCasnueva it fails because Python switches to 'e' notation when the number gets small enough.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is counting the number of zeroes in a string, not a float (i.e. a decimal). The string representation of values such as `0.00000001` in Python looks like `1e-08`, making this answer impossible to use with an actual float value, and it is not possible to cast a float value such as `0.00000001` to a string in Python and get `"0.00000001"` unless you use some kind of string formatting which requires a priori knowledge of the number of zeroes in the float. Leading you right back to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
def num_of_zeros(n):
  s = '{:.16f}'.format(n).split('.')[1]
  return len(s) - len(s.lstrip('0'))


print(num_of_zeros(0.0000456)) # ==> 4
print(num_of_zeros(0.00406))   # ==> 2
print(num_of_zeros(0.000456))  # ==> 3
```

Comment: This one is not right as the second answer would count the 0 between the 4 and 6. We need to count only 0s before the first non 0 digit.

Comment: @PacoCasnueva It's doesn't count the zero between the 4 and the 6, count them yourself, they're two.

Comment: @PacoCasnueva No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorise the log method you gave, using numpy. This should speed it up significantly.

```
import numpy as np
def num_zeros(decimal_vec):
    return np.floor(np.abs(np.log10(decimal_vec)))

input_arr = np.array([0.0000456,0.00406,0.000456])

print(num_zeros(input_arr)) #--> [4. 2. 3.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I do this like that... if that could help...

```
def count_zero_in_decimal_number(number):
    zeros = 0
    while number < 0.1:
        number *= 10
        zeros += 1
    return zeros
```

Generally I don't like to use *while* statements but it does the work. I have tested it with your examples.

Comment: I would have voted up except your variable name doesn’t make sense

Comment: Ok well. I have changed what seemed to bother you I guess. 'no_zero' stands for 'number_of_zeros'. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: I made some edits and upvoted this, hope it’s okay for you. Off my mind this should be the most performing answer out of all mentioned here at this point.

Comment: If the solution is more clear for everybody that is what matters. Thanks for your time and the upvote !

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_num_of_zeros(num):
    if not num:
        return 0
    current_num = abs(num)
    num_of_zeros = -1

    while not (current_num//1):
        current_num *= 10
        num_of_zeros +=1

    return num_of_zeros
```

Comment: Please also explain your answer at least a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exact solution but it may help you with other decimal numbers. It's easy with one line.

```
n = '12.11000000
count = len(n) - len(n.rstrip('0'))
print (count)
```